# How to write JSON to file locally with FileManger and JSONEncoder? Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

So want I'm trying to do is write json created in code to the user local documents directory but can seem to get this to work.

```
struct Puzzle: Codable {
  let id: Int?
  let puzzle: Int?
  let moves: Int?
}

class PuzzleController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create reference to default filemanager object
    let filemgr = FileManager.default

    // get documents directory path
    let dirPath = filemgr.urls(for: .documentsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let docsDir = dirPath[0].path

    // change to current working directory
    filemgr.changeCurrentDirectoryPath(docsDir)

    // create a new directory
    let docsURL = dirPath[0]
    let newDir = docsURL.appendingPathComponent("json").path

    do {
      try filemgr.createDirectory(atPath: newDir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error.localizeDescription)
    }

    // create arrary of json objects
    let jsonPuzzle = [Puzzle(id: 1, puzzle: 1, moves: 1), Puzzle(id: 2, puzzle: 2, moves: 2), Puzzle(id: 3, puzzle: 3, moves: 3)] 

    // create url to json file
    let jURL = URL(string: newDir)?.appendingPathComponent("pjson.json")

    // write to json file
    do {
      let encoder = JSONEncoder()
      encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
      let jsonData = try encoder.encode(jsonPuzzle)
      try jsonData.write(to: jURL)
    } catch let jError {
      print(jError)
    }
  }
}
```

I keep getting CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme and Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=518 "The file couldn’t be saved because the specified URL type isn’t supported."

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper steps needed to write json to a file locally without using a third party api?

The contents of jURL as requested by one of the commenters.
"/Users/blank/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/920F6A0F-E814-49E2-A792-04605361F139/data/Containers/Data/Applicatio ... ir/pjson"

Comment: Maybe you could print `jURL` and add it to your question because the issue seems to be with the url.

Comment: edited the post with the contents of jURL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you lose the protocol (scheme) when you switch back and forth between `URL` and `String` for your paths, using only `URL` will fix your error.

Here is a shortened version of your code that only uses `URL` for directory and file paths to make sure the URL is valid

```
let filemgr = FileManager.default

let dirPath = filemgr.urls(for: .documentsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

let docsURL = dirPath[0]
let newDir = docsURL.appendingPathComponent("json")

do {
  try filemgr.createDirectory(at: newDir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch {
  print(error)
}

let jURL = newDir.appendingPathComponent("pjson.json")
```